# Save the contents of a variable in Xcode Debugger

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging

Running the debugger in Xcode when you set a breakpoint you get a view a variable and can see all of the fantastically interesting values associated with it.

Is there any way to save/export this data to a file?

I am of course having an issue where something is wrong but there is a ton of variables and I want to just compare one run of the program to the next easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gdb for this. The following gdb commands are useful:

```
set log file <filename>
set logging on
... do interesting stuff ...
set logging off
```

This will log the section "do interesting stuff" to  as a text file.

If you want to get really fancy and have a fixed set of commands/variables you want to dump, you can make a function and stick it in `$HOME/.gdbinit`. Then get to a breakpoint and just issue `dumplog` (if using the example below) at the gdb prompt.

```
# Example that just does some random stuff 
define dumplog
    set logging file foo.txt
    b main
    c
    set logging on
    po var1
    po var2
    set logging off
end
```

---

Another approach which I just learned is issuing the following from a terminal. It has the benefit of no manual intervention, but I just tried it and you get quite a bit of extra garbage in that file.

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXGDBDebuggerLogToFile YES
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXGDBDebuggerLogFileName <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over a value, click on the double-headed arrows and you get a pop-up menu with a lot of options:

[alt text http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Print%20Description.png](http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Print%20Description.png)

Print Description will dump the information about the object to the gdb console, from which you can copy and paste it.